# Where to start with Euler and Ramanujan?

Tags: education

What are the specific qualifications for directly studying Euler and Ramanujan's works.Is Hardy's "A Course in Pure Mathematics" a good start?

Comment: That text will probably be a little un accessible as a novice to number theory. Getting to grips with elementary and analytical number theory is where you should start (possibly through using a different text though). EDIT: For some reason I thought you said 'An introduction to the theory of numbers', disregard my reply.

Comment: Going back to the "masters" is a good thing. Euler is clear enough in many parts, but I think you need exegetes to understand how such piece of work is inserted into the panorama of mathematics at that time; I advise you to have a look at a review of history of mathematics and see the articles devoted e.g. to Euler and study these parts in priority. Why are you targeting these two ? Gauss is more understable source than the very-very-hard-to-understand Ramanujan. Some books of Newton are very nicely  written (even the Principia, with comments by Chandrasekar).

Comment: I understand that Ramanujan is quite incomprehensible , but I cannot find Euler's Opera Omnia translated in English. What about G.H Hardy's book is it a good start ?

Comment: Most writing (and translations!) from Euler are available at ["The Euler Archive"](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/) and a good start to his Work(s!) is given by Sandifer in his "How Euler did it" linked [there](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/index.html) at the left. An excellent start to Ramanujan's work is Hardy's book [Ramanujan](http://www.amazon.com/Ramanujan-Lectures-Subjects-Suggested-Publishing/dp/0821820230/) but this requires of course some maturity in calculus and Hardy's "A Course in Pure M..." could indeed help,